# Why don't Windows 7clients in a 2k3 domain network give admin access to domain admins

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-7

I've recently (I know, we're way behind the times) started adding Windows 7 (Ultimate) clients to a 2k3 AD network.  Previously everything was running Windows XP SP3.

In XP SP3, after I joined a computer to the domain, it would automatically treat `MYDOMAIN\Domain Admins` as a local administrator on the computer.  That made *tons* of tasks easier (remote management, troubleshooting, configuration, etc).

My new Windows 7 clients *do not* behave this way.  Instead, I have to explicitly add `MYDOMAIN\Domain Admins` to the `LOCALCOMPUTERNAME\Administrators` group to get access.  Why is this happening and is there a way to change it?

Comment: That's really strange, I got "Domain Admins" in my local Administrators group automatically, either on XP or 7(Professional version).
Maybe a specific group policy is used that changed the default behavior.

Comment: couple of things to check.  1) gpresult (check group policies applied), 2) check "system" event log on the client after adding to the domain.

Answer (score 3):

I have seen such a behavior already (and apparently, you and me are [not the only ones](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverDS/thread/dcff7b65-f813-4b91-8f88-6f8d19b9f924)).

In my case, the problem was caused by having machines with duplicate SID in the domain due to a HDD clone followed by a sysprep *without* having checked the "generalized" checkbox. You can get the same issue if you're running cloned/P2Ved VMs.

Comment: AFAIK there's no cloned machines on the network.  I'm installing directly from media.  I'll have a look at the SIDs to see if this is the issue though.

Comment: Well, it was worth a try anyway